# DROP CONSTRAINT auto-generated column CHECK in mariaDB

Tags: mariadb, constraints

I have a table with a `CHECK` on a column. The check was not added explicitly with a specific name, so it gets an auto-generated name.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL CHECK (quantity > 0)
);
SELECT TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM information_schema.check_constraints;
```

output:

```
TABLE_NAME  CONSTRAINT_NAME
test    quantity
```

But it seems I cannot `DROP` this constraint by its auto-generated name.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `test` DROP CONSTRAINT `quantity`;
```

output:

```
ERROR 1091 (42000) at line 8: Can't DROP CONSTRAINT `quantity`; check that it exists
```

This procedure works on MySQL (with a different auto-generated name), but does not seem to work in mariaDB 10.7.8. How can I drop this check?

Comment: Note [10.7.8](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10-7-8-release-notes/) was a short term release series that is now out of maintenance. If you do find something not working logically in mariadb please report a [bug](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CHECK` here is given as part of the column definition, you can remove it using `MODIFY COLUMN`:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
  MODIFY COLUMN `quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

But if it is added using `CONSTRAINT [constraint_name] CHECK (expression)` for example :

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `quantity` INT(11) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT quantity_check CHECK (`quantity` > 0)
);
```

Then you can remove it using `DROP CONSTRAINT` :

```
ALTER TABLE `test` DROP CONSTRAINT quantity_check ;
```

Comment: Thanks! The `MODIFY COLUMN` approach works on mariaDB. Whereas it does not work on MySQL. Vice-serse the `DROP CONSTRAINT` approach works on MySQL but not on mariaDB.

Learning for the future: Use `ADD CONSTRAINT` with an explicit name to avoid situations like these.